# how can we adjust the height and width of a lightning-card in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any way to do this?
I am working in Visual studio code using LWC

```
<template>
 
  
   <lightning-card style = "width:1000px;height:1000px"> //I tried like this, but this is not working
    <lightning-button variant="brand"
    label="New Estimation"
    title="New Quotation"
    onclick={openModal}
    class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    <lightning-button variant="brand"
    label="Mail"
    title="Open Mail"
    onclick={openMail}
    class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi @Athira, your question is very open ended, kindly update your question with specific details about the problem and also do share on what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see where it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed it within a div which utilizes SLDS sizing utilities or custom styling

```
<template>

    <!-- Small card -->
    <div class="slds-size_small">
        <lightning-card  title="Hello">
            <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
            <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>

    <!-- Custom style card -->
    <div style="height:25px; margin:20px; margin-bottom:150px;">
        <lightning-card  title="Hello">
            <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
            <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>

    <!-- Normal card -->
    <lightning-card  title="Hello">
        <lightning-button label="New" slot="actions"></lightning-button>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body (custom component)</p>
        <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/

Comment: Hi Max, I have tried using slds-size and custom styling, But there is no change in the lightning-card. These stylings are not getting reflected in my lightning-card. Don't know why?

Comment: Now its working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I found answer from Max not always applicable in my cases, you can try this:

```
<div class="slds-card" style="height:12345px; width:12345px">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

Template

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <lightning-card>

    </lightning-card>
</div>
</template>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50%;
  }
```